# count if and search in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

```
=COUNTIF(AND(A:A="01.01.2015";B:B="torsvik";ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wt";C:C)));TRUE)
```

I would like to count "wt"s on "01.01.2015" and "torsvik", but it is giving an error. Could you give your advice ?

if a is true , and b is true and c is true , count it . in my example, it should be 2.

Comment: use `COUNTIFS`, the one with 'S'

Comment: What is the correct number? I don't understand if it's supposed to return 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Excel is English based, so first of all replace your `;` with `,`

Comment: if a is true , and b is true and c is true , count it . in my example, it should be 2.

Comment: @Saba is your column A (dates) are in a Date format `dd.mm.yyyy` or is it a Text ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Excel can use `;` as a delimiter in European based versions. It depends on the regional settings you have in windows.

Comment: @Saba see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you formatted your cells in Column A as text, then use the formula below:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"=01.01.2015",B:B,"=torsvik",C:C,"=*wt*")
```

If your settings are in European version (as mentioned here by rohl), then use the formula below :

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;"=01.01.2015";B:B;"=torsvik";C:C;"=*wt*")
```

As you can see, I am using the wildcard `*` to check for all types of `wt` in column C:

[image]

When simulating your table's data a little, and changing "torsvik" to "marco" the result changes to 1, see image below:

[image]

If you formatted your cells in Column A as Date (as in "dd.mm.yyyy") , then use the formula below:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"=1/1/2015",B:B,"=torsvik",C:C,"=*wt*")
```

Once again, for European settings, change to :

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;"=1/1/2015";B:B;"=torsvik";C:C;"=*wt*")
```

Or, if your date settings are also different, maybe you need to modify to:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;"=01.01.2015";B:B;"=torsvik";C:C;"=*wt*")
```

See image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, you can use `COUNTIFS` to do this quite easily. Here the formula I would use:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B3;"torsvik";A1:A3;"01.01.2015")
```

If the date is an actual date format, you can also simply link to a cell that is of the same format where you write the value you are looking for.